# Problem with foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, preg-match-all

I made this code :

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/"Type":".+?",/', $text, $matches);


foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    if (isset($_GET['dvd']) && !empty($_GET['dvd'])) {
        $dvd = $_GET['dvd'];
        if (stripos($match, 'DVD') !== false) {
            $match = '';
        }
    }
    echo $match;
}
```

In this code i search for the word "type" in $text and it stores the whole line with the words ahead of it in the array. And then i loop through each one and see if the word DVD is there. If it is then, it removes it and displays a blank line.

---

Now I also want to search for suppose manufacturer and display it beneath every type returned.

So it should return suppose the result :

```
Type: HDD
Manufacturer: WD

Type: Flash Drive
Manufacturer: Transcend

Type: CD
Manufacturer: Sony
```

So I tried it with putting another preg_match_all expression:

```
$anotherMatch = array();
preg_match_all('/"Manufacturer":".+?",/', $text, $anotherMatch);
```

And I tried combining this with the previous foreach expression with an && operator but it didn't work. Also I tried different foreach expressions and then one for echoing at the end. but that also didn't work.

Can you tell me how to achieve the desired result. Thanks...

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example of the text you're trying to get the information out of?

Comment: the text will be unformatted text without any HTML and everything is working fine with only one search and echo. But I want to add two as i can print both together.

Comment: We'll need an example if we're supposed to know how a regex which gets both will function however.

Comment: Not directly related but you can simplify the line `if (isset($_GET['dvd']) && !empty($_GET['dvd'])) {` by this : `if (!empty($_GET['dvd'])) {` the empty() function will check if the variable is set.

Comment: thanks TrexXXx for the code. It simplified my code a lot. cause i have too many of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Given source input like this:

```
"Type":"HDD",
"Manufacturer":"WD",
"Other":"Nonsense",
"Type":"Flash Drive",
"Manufacturer":"Transcend",
"Other":"More nonsense",
"Type":"CD",
"Manufacturer":"Sony",
"Other":"Yet even more nonsense",
```

And expecting output like this:

```
Type: HDD
Manufacturer: WD

Type: Flash Drive
Manufacturer: Transcend

Type: CD
Manufacturer: Sony
```

You could use this regular expression:

```
/"(Type|Manufacturer)":"([^"]+?)",/
```

And loop over it like this:

```
preg_match_all('/"(Type|Manufacturer)":"([^"]+?)",/', $text, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match => $line)
{
    if (!empty($_GET['dvd']) && stripos($matches[2], 'DVD') !== false)
    {
        continue;
    }
    echo $matches[1][$match] . ': ' . $matches[2][$match] . "\n";
}
```

Although, I don't think that will do quite exactly what you want it to.